# Web application design pattern for optional paid extensions

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, business-logic

I am building a web application in which users can buy some widgets or plugins to use inside the app. Now my question is should I package all widgets/plugins with the app or let the users download them as downloadable extensions? I want to know which one is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mix both options using Lazy Loading design pattern. This way you can package all the widgets inside the main app, and make the client load on the background (when logging in or after buying someone) only the ones he already have purchased.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading